# Google Chrome: Unhandled Promise.reject() global handling via the window.onunhandledrejection event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise

Windows 10 x64
Google Chrome 62.0.3202.94 x64

My code snippet:

```js
let rejected;

// unhandled rejection handling...
window.onunhandledrejection = function(e) {
 // Handle this case... For example I can send info
 // about this error to developer's email.
 console.log('Unhandled rejection info:');
 console.log(e.type);
 console.log(e.reason.message);
 console.log(rejected === e.promise);
};

// Some unhandled rejection...
rejected = Promise.reject(new Error('Foo'));
```

This code works in the stackoverflow code snippet, but it doesn't work if I try to use it in my js-file in GoogleChrome:

[image]

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: hey! Have you figured out what's causing it?

Comment: The code works as expected after adding `bluebird` promise library. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.5.1/bluebird.core.js"></script>`. Though it's still a mystery why native promise implementations don't do the job (both in latest Firefox and Chrome)